# Is there any way that a Data Loader CLI can connect to the two different sandboxes at the same time?

Tags: apex, data-loader

Scheduled batch jobs in Server is using Apex Data loader CLI to extract data from sandbox. And now we are having one more new sandbox where we need same functionalities including data extraction.

Is there any way that batch jobs can access both the sandboxes at the same time.

Can we add two sandboxes credentials in the config file.

Comment: What sort of operation do you have in mind for which you want to connect to 2 different orgs?

Comment: @RajeshShah, We want a same batch job to run for two different organisations at the same time via Apex Data Loader CLI. For ex, ExtractData batch job should extract the data from org1 and org2. How to configure these two org credentials in Apex data loader configuration file.

Comment: @RajeshShah, can we install two different data loader versions in the same windows server, so that i can point two different sandboxes in the config files of respective data loader versions? Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think you can use 2 different versions as they would be in the same directory and might share the same conf.xml file